# Vector repite los datos de una consulta

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, netbeans, array

mi problema es que tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
        SELECT respuestaId, respuesta, estado, r.preguntaId FROM respuestas r, preguntas p WHERE r.preguntaId = p.preguntaId AND r.preguntaId = 1
```

El resultado de la consulta son 4 respuestas, por ejemplo "resp1", "resp2", "resp3", "resp4". Lo guardo en el vector de la siguiente manera:

```
        clsMtoRespuestas resp = new clsMtoRespuestas();
             resp.setPreguntaId(pregunta);

             if(resp.ConsultarRespuestasPorPregunta()) {
                  for(int i = 0; i <= 3;i++){
                  respuestas[i] = resp.getRespuesta();
                  }
             }
```

Mi idea es que cada respuesta se guarde en un espacio del vector pero a la hora de mostrar estas respuestas en unos jButtons muestra que solo la primera respuesta("resp1") se ha guardado en los 4 espacios del vector.

(Pongo tambien el codigo de como los muestro para que no quede duda de si yo soy el que repite los indices)

```
        btnResp1.setText(respuestas[0]);
        btnResp2.setText(respuestas[3]);
        btnResp3.setText(respuestas[1]);
        btnResp4.setText(respuestas[2]);
```

Quiero saber si hay un error en la forma de guardar las respuestas en el vector o si habra otra manera de hacerlo. De antemano, gracias.

Llamo los datos desde una clase de esta manera:

```
        public boolean ConsultarRespuestasPorPregunta() {
             boolean resp = false;
             try{
                  String sql = "SELECT respuestaId, respuesta, estado, r.preguntaId FROM respuestas r, preguntas p WHERE r.preguntaId = p.preguntaId AND r.preguntaId = ?;";
                  PreparedStatement cmd = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
                  cmd.setInt(1, preguntaId);
                  ResultSet rs = cmd.executeQuery();
                  if(rs.next()){
                      resp = true;
                      respuestaId = rs.getInt(1);
                      respuesta = rs.getString(2);
                      estado = rs.getInt(3);
                      preguntaId = rs.getInt(4);
                  }
                  cmd.close();
                  //getCn().close();

             }
             catch (SQLException e){
                  System.out.println(e.toString());
             }
             return resp;
       }
```

Comment: Casi... te tengo una respuesta, pero... ¿cuál es tu manejador de base de datos (MySQL, Postegresql, Oracle, SQL Server...)?

Comment: Hola, vas a tener que mostrar mas de tu codigo. donde se guardan las respuestas, como se consultan, para que veamos si el problema no viene por otro lado. mira [ask]

Comment: Utilizo SQLServer 2014.

Comment: En el fragmento de codigo de **ConsultarRespuestasPorPregunta()** te hace falta guardar todos los resultado en un array o lista de elementos; inicializar algun elemento **indiceActual** a 0 y por cada **getRespuesta()** obtener el valor en *indiceActual*; incrementar *indiceActual* y retornar el valor. Claro con su respectivo tratamiento de cuando llegas al final de los elementos. *PD.: Use poco Java pero la lógica te la comparto*

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas te refieres a usar un vector dentro del metodo que hace la consulta? Hice esto:   `String res[] = new String[4];
                for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                    respuesta = rs.getString(2);
                    res[i] = respuesta;
                }`    Y el resultado siempre se repite

Comment: @AndresHenriquez añade ese codigo a la pregunta por favor. Como dijo alla arriba Roberto, estas guardando el resulset en variables, y no en una clase o vector o en algun objeto que te permita iterar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este tipo de problemas yo suelo usar en MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT` combinado con `GROUP BY`.

Recomiendo usar esta forma, sobre todo si en la consulta todos los demás datos serán siempre los mismos, excepto las respuestas. **Imagina la de datos redundantes que tendrás si la consulta recupera 50 ó 100 respuestas**, estamos hablando de 50 ó 100 filas con lo mismo: `Pregunta 1, Pregunta 1, Pregunta 1`, etc, donde lo único que variará será la respuesta.

Entonces, mejor agrupar los datos y concatenar las respuestas con un separador ¿no?, de ese modo manejarás una sola fila de datos.

Desgraciadamente esa función no existe en SQL Server, pero podemos simular algo parecido haciendo esto:

```
SELECT
     t1.[preguntaId],
     STUFF(
         (SELECT '|' + respuesta
          FROM respuestas_20170906 r
          INNER JOIN preguntas_20170906 p ON r.[preguntaId]=p.[preguntaId]
          WHERE r.[preguntaId]=1
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS respuestas 
FROM respuestas_20170906 AS t1 WHERE t1.[preguntaId]=1
GROUP BY [preguntaId];
```

Tendrás una columna `respuestas` con datos parecidos a estos:

```
Respuesta1|Respuesta2|Respuesta3|Respuesta5
```

Haciendo un `split` mediante `|` tendrás un array con las respuestas. De ese modo estarás manejando una sola fila con todos tus datos y no tendrás necesidad de bucles para leerlos.

---

#### `Código:` <kbd>[VER EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/DMFIN67689)</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE  preguntas_20170906
    ([preguntaId] int, [pregunta] varchar(30))
;


CREATE TABLE  respuestas_20170906
    ([respuestaId] int, [respuesta] varchar(30), [preguntaId] int, [estado] int)
;



INSERT INTO preguntas_20170906
    ([preguntaId], [pregunta])
VALUES
    (1, 'Pregunta1'),
    (2, 'Pregunta2'),
    (3, 'Pregunta3'),
    (4, 'Pregunta4')
;


INSERT INTO respuestas_20170906
    ([respuestaId], [respuesta], [preguntaId])
VALUES
    (1, 'Respuesta1', 1),
    (2, 'Respuesta2', 1),
    (3, 'Respuesta3', 2),
    (4, 'Respuesta4', 1),
    (5, 'Respuesta5', 1)

;


-- SELECT * FROM respuestas_20170906;
-- SELECT * FROM preguntas_20170906;



SELECT
     t1.[preguntaId],
     STUFF(
         (SELECT '|' + respuesta
          FROM respuestas_20170906 r
          INNER JOIN preguntas_20170906 p ON r.[preguntaId]=p.[preguntaId]
--          WHERE r.[preguntaId] = t1.[preguntaId] AND r.[preguntaId]=1
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS respuestas 
FROM respuestas_20170906 AS t1 WHERE t1.[preguntaId]=1
GROUP BY [preguntaId];
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
preguntaId      respuestas
1               Respuesta1|Respuesta2|Respuesta3|Respuesta5
```

---

Si necesitas concatenar más de una columna:

-- Varios valores concatenados: puesto que estado es INT hay que hacer un CAST

```
SELECT
     t1.[preguntaId],
     STUFF(
         (SELECT '|' + respuesta + '_' + CAST(estado AS VARCHAR)
          FROM respuestas_20170906 r
          INNER JOIN preguntas_20170906 p ON r.[preguntaId]=p.[preguntaId]
          WHERE r.[preguntaId]=1
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS respuestas 
FROM respuestas_20170906 AS t1 WHERE t1.[preguntaId]=1
GROUP BY [preguntaId];
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
preguntaId     respuestas
1              Respuesta1_10|Respuesta2_50|Respuesta4_90|Respuesta5_33
```

Aquí tendrías que hacer split primero sobre `|` y luego sobre `_` para obtener:

```
Respuesta1
 10
Respuesta2
 50
Respuesta4
 90
Respuesta5
 33
```

Comment: no creo que su problema sea en la BD... me parece que trae mal los datos a la view...

Comment: Lee bien, el trae los datos en cuatro filas y los lee en un bucle `for`, con esta consulta puede traer sus datos ya listos en una sola columna: `Respuesta1|Respuesta2|Respuesta3|Respuesta5` y hacer split sobre esa columna.

Comment: Te lo tomo y es muy valiosa la respuesta. No comparto la idea de tirarle semejante query a la bd para solucionar un problema de la view, pero +1

Comment: No @gbianchi es una consulta normal, si las tablas están bien indexadas. Es más, te ahorras en _transporte de datos_ ya que de otra forma puedes tener viajando datos redundantes, mientras que aquí tienes una sola fila, no cuatro filas.

Comment: Tu respuesta me ha ayudado mucho en cuanto a la consulta pero tambien debo de buscar el estado de las respuestas ya que con eso manejo si es correcto o incorrecto, (estoy viendo la manera de llamar ese dato tambien, no es problema), el problema es que no me queda claro como mostar los datos en los botones` @A.Cedano

Comment: @AndresHenriquez he editado el código con una forma de obtener también el estado. En cuanto lo que dices de los botones, si tengo tiempo ahora lo miro.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Buen día

Como te mencione recuerdo (y use) casi nada de Java lo siguiente espero te de idea de mi planteamiento y lo "traduzcas" como en la realidad te sea de utilidad.

```
class clsMtoRespuestas {

   private int indiceActual; // aqui el elemento a obtener
   private int[] respuestaId; // iniciarlizarlo 
   private string[] respuesta; // iniciarlizarlo 
   private int[] estado; // iniciarlizarlo 
   private int[] preguntaId; // iniciarlizarlo 

    public boolean ConsultarRespuestasPorPregunta() {
         boolean resp = false;
          /* Inicializar los vecrores */
          indiceActual=0; /* creo recordar el primer elemento es en posición 0 (cero) */
         try{
              String sql = "SELECT respuestaId, respuesta, estado, r.preguntaId FROM respuestas r, preguntas p WHERE r.preguntaId = p.preguntaId AND r.preguntaId = ?;";
              PreparedStatement cmd = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
              cmd.setInt(1, preguntaId);
              ResultSet rs = cmd.executeQuery();
              /*if(rs.next()){*/ /* En vez del if usar while */
              while (rs.next())
                  resp = true;
                  /* Asumiendo cada vector inicializado con tantos elemento como devuelve la consulta
                     usamos temporalmente indiceActual para llenarlo */
                  respuestaId[indiceActual] = rs.getInt(1);
                  respuesta[indiceActual] = rs.getString(2);
                  estado[indiceActual] = rs.getInt(3);
                  preguntaId[indiceActual] = rs.getInt(4);
                  indiceActual++; /* Incrementar indice actual */
              }
              cmd.close();
              //getCn().close();
             /* terminamos de obtener todo y ponesmo indiceActual en 0 (cero) */
             indiceActual=0;
         }
         catch (SQLException e){
              System.out.println(e.toString());
         }
         return resp;
    } // ConsultarRespuestasPorPregunta

    public string getRespuesta() {
       /* Asumo est devuelve el vector "respuesta" */ 
       string devolver= respuesta[indiceActual]; /* tomamos el valor */
       return devolver;
    } // getRespuesta

    public boolean next() {
       indiceActual++; /* Incrementamos indiceActual */
       /* Pensado todos los vectores tienen la misma cantidad de elementos
          usamos cualquiera para comprobar si llegamos al final */
       return (respuesta.length<indiceActual);
    } // next
}
```

Con lo anterior para la parte que tienes:

```
clsMtoRespuestas resp = new clsMtoRespuestas();
resp.setPreguntaId(pregunta);

if(resp.ConsultarRespuestasPorPregunta()) {
  int i =0;
  while(resp.next())
     respuestas[i++] = resp.getRespuesta();
  }
}
```

Esperando haber comprendido lo que deseas hacer deseo te sirva de orientación.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, el unico problema es en el ultimo bloque de codigo al usar `resp.next` porque me da un error en "next", mas claramente no se puede usar ahi... Y usando la forma que esta en la pregunta me da este error `El conjunto de resultados no tiene fila actual.`

Comment: Puede **next** sea palabra reservada o precise algún palabra adicional par permitirlo/sobreescribirlo; prueba como **Next** o ya de plano **Siguiente** :D según lo permita. Respecto al mensaje de error que mencionas; de ser posible indica en que parte o momento ocurre para hacerte sugerencias.

Comment: Cuando deberia cargar las preguntas, primero me muestra un `JavaNullPointerExcepton` (Se que significa que estoy mandando algo nulo, no entiendo que sera) y luego de eso el error que antes mencione

Comment: ¿pusiste el código para niciar los vectores antes de **rs.next()** que esta en el  while?

Comment: Si, puse el codigo.

Comment: Mira; copie y pegue tu código; me parece el error esta en los **rs.get[...]();** el primero tiene 1 y debe ser cero ; es decir **respuestaId[indiceActual] = rs.getInt(1);** sería **respuestaId[indiceActual] = rs.getInt(0);**... **preguntaId[indiceActual] = rs.getInt(3);**

Comment: No, asi se manejan estas variables... Da otro error si se usa el 0

Comment: Otra que veo; estoy usando **preguntaId** como vector y tu lo usas para pasar un dato; te sugiero crees otra variable para pasar ese dato (que me parece lo asignas en **resp.setPreguntaId(pregunta);**

Comment: Tambien cambie los nombres de las variables

Comment: Sinceramente ya me asquee un poco, llevo demasiado tiempo viendo este proyecto.... Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, vere como resolver el error, gracias.